# How to trace through a recursive method in java with the original method name passed in as an argument

Tags: java, recursion

I have been given a sample exercise on recursion. I am able to trace through recursive methods flawlessly overall, but there is one recursive method that I'm having a problem tracing through.

```
static int fg(int x) {
    if (x < 5) {
        return x * x + 1;
    }

    if (x == 5) {
        return x * x - 3;
    }

    return fg(x - 2);
}
```

I would know how to trace through this code generally BUT, the question says "what value is returned from the method call fg(fg(fg(3)))?"

Have you any ideas on how to trace through this code with that kind of a method invocation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider each function function calls separately.
Step 1: First fg(3) => this returns 3 * 3 + 1 = 10
Step 2: Next fg(10) => satisfying neither of the conditions related to 5, control goes to the last statement return fg(10 - 2)
hence fg(8) => fg(6) => fg(4); 
now 4 satisfies the first condition; returns 4 * 4 + 1 = 17;
Step 3: now last fragment fg(17); Similar to step 2 this number reduces by 2 recursively till it becomes less than or equal to 5 to satisfy either of the first 2 if blocks;
fg(17) => fg(15) => fg(13) => fg(11) => fg(9) => fg(7) => fg(5)
now being 5 the 2nd if block is satisfied; therefore returns 5 * 5 - 3 = 22;

That's your final answer!

Answer (score 0):

The original method name isn't being passed as an argument.  The argument is declared to be an `int`, and neither a method name nor a method reference is an `int`.  Instead, the inner-most method `fg(3)` is called, and its return value becomes the argument for the surrounding invocation, whose return value then becomes the argument of the outer-most invocation.

Think of it as being equivalent to:

```
int first = fg(3);
int second = fg(first);
int answer = fg(second);
```

only without the temporary variables.